# How to set a pre-condition to the evaluation of a static_assert?

Tags: c++, templates, static-assert

I have this function for zero-overwriting things which uses static_assert to check if the given thing's type is a POD type:

```
template <bool safeMode = true, typename generic>
void overwriteWithZeros( generic *variableAddress )
{
    if (safeMode) static_assert(std::is_pod<generic>::value, "Only POD types can be properly overwriten");

    const size_t size = sizeof(generic);
    unsigned char *variableData = (unsigned char*)(variableAddress);

    for (size_t i = 0; i < size; i++)
        variableData[i] = 0;
}
```

which I call here:

```
int main()
{
    being *creature = new being(100, "a guinea pig"); // being is not a POD type

    overwriteWithZeros<false>(creature);
    // totally unrelated stuff...
}
```

And since `safeMode` is a compile time value, I don't know why it happens that being it true or being it false, static_assert always "happens", giving me the then expected error for `being` being not a POD type, as if this `if` before the static_assert simply wasn't there.

So, what am I doing wrong here?

Since you confirmed my suspicions (`if` itself is evaluated at run time despite of `safeMode` being a compile time value or not, while `static_assert` is evaluated at compile time), I changed the main question to:

**What could I do to achieve what I'm trying here, so?**

Comment: Because `if` is evaluated at run time, and `static_assert` is evaluated at compile time.

Comment: *"what could I do to achieve what I'm trying here"* - `static_assert` does not cost anything. Remove the `safeMode` parameter and keep the assertion unconditionally.

Comment: I could do this, but I wanted a switch to enable the safe checking of the type, so that if you Really want to overwrite something which is not a POD you can do this and take the consequences.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that `static_assert` is evaluated at compile time, this means that when the compiler finds it, then it evaluates it, regardless of where it is (unless it's excluded with a macro like `#ifdef`). To solve this problem you should make the enable flag part of the evaluation itself:

```
static_assert(!safeMode || std::is_pod<generic>::value, "Only POD types can be properly overwriten");
```

This is allowed because `safeMode` is a compile time value (being a template argument).

In both situations the `static_assert` will be evaluated but with `safeMode == false` it will always evaluate to `true`.

Comment: I thought exactly that, since safeMode was a compile time value, what I was trying to do might have worked... So when it did not, I got confused about what was possible to do...

Comment: The fact that is a compile time constant doesn't alter the semantics of an if statement. The only difference is that when optimizing the branch `if (false)` would disappear from generated code. But this happens after compilation, and in any case `static_assert` doesn't emit any code.

Answer (score 2):

`static_assert` means exactly that, the assertion is done statically at compile time.